# Why is the while loop never executed?

Tags: c++, while-loop, flags

I am working on a simple program to test the while loop with flags.

However I am uncertain why my program does not even enter the while loop for some reasons, do pardon me if I've made simple errors.

MAIN

```
int main()
{
  int xflag=0;
  int n=0;

while ( xflag==1 )
{
    if (n == 10)
    {

        cout<<"exiting loop"<<endl;
        xflag = 1;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << n << endl;
        ++n;
        xflag = 0;
    }

}

cout<<"hey"<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

THE OUTPUT

```
   hey
```

Comment: You probably meant `while ( xflag==0 )`

Comment: No, he probably meant to do `xflag == 1`. You see that he does `xflag == 0` inside the loop to break it.

Comment: @EitanT -  No, he obviously wants to loop while `xflag==0` and when n reaches 10 to change it to 1. anyway thats my understanding

Comment: xflag == 0 would be correct, he actually changes xflag = 1 to break out of the loop, or t least attempt to, which it wouldn't as it is.

Comment: +1: @WeaselFox Actually you're right. I read it wrong. Voting up.

Answer (score 1):

Right. The body of `while` loop will execute if `xflag == 1`. But it's not.

Since you set `x = 1` to exit the loop, what you need is probably changing the condition `xflag == 1` to `xflag == 0` (or simpy `!xflag`).

Answer (score 0):

The value of `xflag` is `0`. Thus the condition `xflag == 1` is returning `false`. This is the reason the control is not coming inside the while loop.